# Powering a microcontroller during sleep periods

Tags: microcontroller, low-power, power-management

In general, what is the best practice for powering a battery-powered uC during its sleep periods? I have a uC driven system that does a bunch of stuff for perhaps 10% of the time, and spends the rest in low-power sleep mode. When it's running, I would use a low-IQ switching regulator to power everything, such as the TI [TPS72840](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS62840#tech-docs). What's the best way to power the uC while it's sleeping, and drawing nA? I was thinking of putting an LDO in parallel with the switcher, but I'd have to diode-isolate it.

Comment: What input voltage are we talking about? There are commercial switching+linear regulators on the market as well as app notes on combining two to do exactly what you describe.

Comment: look at how RTC modules are designed

Comment: ultra-low-power microcontrollers often have a separate "VBat" or similar supply rail, which can be more or less directly connected to a lithium coin cell to sustain deep sleep modes for months, often decades.

Comment: 60nA not low enough for you? What is the power source?

Comment: I hate it when I see *"best practice"* questions. There is no such thing as *always best no matter the situation*. The Sieko Message watch would turn on an FM RF receiver every so often every single day. It would, if you drove into a new town somewhere, have to hunt around to find an FM station that was broadcasting messages for it and that hunting process cost energy. Once found, less energy to listen on occasion, though. For all of this and using a western digital 6502 MCU inside, the whole watch ran for 2 years on a single, small lithium watch battery. Just a benchmark for you.

Comment: What’s the microcontroller, and what are the active and sleep currents involved? Active 10% of the time is a lot, if you draw 50 mA active and 20 uA in sleep (typical figure for an ESP32 for instance, not taking into account wireless or any external components), 10% active time will account for 99.6% of the power draw, so saving a few nA won’t matter much…

Comment: It doesn't matter what the microcontroller is, it's a general question. During sleep periods very little power is required and a switcher can waste power vs an LDO. While awake, a switcher is more efficient.